# reading micro SD card directly from PC

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card

Is it possible to read a microSD card (on a breakout) through the USB port on the arduino? or perhaps another USB port I could attach to the breakout?  Basically, I would like to read data off the card with my laptop without having to go and remove it each time!

Comment: yes, that is possible

Comment: @jsotola Really? I wonder how (I thought the Arduino did not support USB to be used within a sketch, at least by default).

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, use the serial connection for the data transfer ... the OP inquired about the possibility of data transfer ... i do not see a requirement to emulate a flash drive

Comment: @jsotola ok than I think we have about the same idea (I deleted my answer based on your comment, now undeleted, shoot at it if it is incorrect though).

Comment: doesn't every PC have a SD card reader?

Comment: @201, Just in case it is not clear from the comments or answers:  USB contains many different protocols.  The Arduino uses the USB serial protocol.  An SDCard uses the USB mass storage protocol.  Not many, if any, USB peripherals can switch between protocols. I see you have not picked a correct answer yet.  If you want me to elaborate in yet another answer - add a comment stating so.

Comment: @Juraj Probably yes, but I think he does not want to remove the SD card ... actually in my project I also am thinking about building the SD card somewhere inside the device (thus not accessible from outside) because it makes building it in an enclosure much easier.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, In my project I show/download the files from SD over a web server

Comment: @juraj sounds like a great idea!

Comment: @MichelKeijazers can you share the program with me?

Comment: @st2000 another protocol like SPI right? can you give me more info about how to do this?

Comment: @201, I think Majenko answered your question the best.  But, to add a bit, for complex protocols, there are physical layers / upper layers (USB) and lower layers (USB serial or USB mass storage & others).  The SDCard will need to use USB mass storage and the Arduino interface always uses USB serial.  Yes, at the SDCard one of two possible physical layers is SPI.  But by the time you get to the USB  port, an SDCard is using USB mass storage.  And, unfortunately, that is not what the Arduino supports on its USB port. The Arduino is of course supporting USB serial.

Comment: @st2000 So,it is possible to use SPI  to make connection between SD card and Arduino serial, right? the project i'm working on demands the last year's data stored in SD card and show it on PC without ejecting the SD card from shield data logger... it sound complicated to me...

Comment: Although, I think i found the answer, i can just ask the serial port to write the file saved in SD card for me with this command : Serial.write(dataFile.read());

Comment: so here is another question... can i save data for along time in my SD card? for example for one year?

Comment: [This web site](https://integralmemory.com/faq/how-long-will-data-stay-valid-memory-card) claims ~10 years.

Comment: @st2000 thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It would be very useful, but afaik this is not possible, since the Arduino sketch you write communicates to the PC via the serial interface only.

The IDE/Arduino driver can use the USB to write your sketch and use the USB for communicating, but for sketches the USB (as direct medium) is not possible.

The SD card will not show up as a specific drive/map/folder on your PC.

Since you want to read the SD card, write in your sketch code to transmit the file(s) you want to send to the PC, to transfer them by UART, and on the PC write a program that reads the serial port and processes it.

Answer (score 1):

In general that's possible. But you can't read the sd card through the arduino's usb port. Instead you have to read the sd card via another protocol, e.g. SPI (look for the apropriate library) and send it to the pc via serial. You'll need software on the pc side to write the content that was read from the arduino to a file.

Take a look at the [SD card tutorial](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-to-sd-card-module-with-arduino/) to see how to read it.

Comment: so, if i want to lets say read the last year history of my data from data logger, can i use SPI to make this connection between SD card and arduino? do you have an example code that may be useful?

Comment: There are examples and tutorials out in the internet (I found one for you). But may I ask why you want to use an arduino? Don't you have an sd card reader to use with usb on your laptop?

Comment: @201, and how is it wired for data logging? not over SPI?

Comment: you're right, but that's actually the project i'm working on right now..

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done with an Arduino, but it can be done with other microcontrollers. You need a microcontroller with a direct USB ("native") connection plus a USB stack that is capable of acting as a USB Mass Storage Device.  Something like the Teensy or chipKIT series of boards can do that.

Then you can write software that will, on command, detach the SD card from your normal sketch operation and re-attach it to the MSD device in the USB stack. You can then read and write to the SD card (though your sketch otherwise cannot access it) as much as you like - then "unmount" the MSD device and detach the SD card from it, at which point your sketch is then free to re-attach itself to the card and start using it again.

Note that the important thing here is that only one functionality can work at a time - either you can read and write the files on the card with your sketch, *or* you can export the device through MSD. Never both. That way leads to filesystem corruption and loss of data.